# Postgresql how to join two tables and get the last valid date before a date of a second column

Tags: postgresql

Due to a migration of data requirements, I am trying to build a PostgreSQL `UPDATE` query which is joining 2 tables and updating the other table's column with a value base on a `CASE` statement

As a start, I have a working DBFiddle here [link to fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vIm5-B_o)

The query is the last one I'm interested in.

Sharing it here also below.

The query purpose is to join at the `candidate_id` and on the last `statuses.type` the candidate has before the `comments.created_at.  Then based on the` CASE`save the right value`AT_CALLCENTER`or` AT_SITE`at the`stage`column in`comments` table.

Right now I'm saving the value but is not correct as I need to join at the last valid statuses.type timestamp before or equal the comments.created_at.

From the fiddle, in the last result if you check the column stage for candidate_id=329 the first row and last row in the table. I have as a value in both AT_SITE but the last one should be AT_CALLCENTER.

You can easily see from the statuses table and compare the dates

| COMMENTS CREATED_AT | STATUSES TIMESTAMP | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-04-26 08:24:14.916743+01 | 2019-04-25 10:36:50.100466+01 | PENDING_CALLCENTER |

The comment as you see from the above table was created the 26-04 and the type the 25-04 so the stage value should be AT_CALLCENTER in this case.

I'm at this point unsure what to change or add to the query to make it work as intended

The goal of this UPDATE is to SET the stage column with the right value based on when the comment was created and what was the last status before it

```
UPDATE
    "comments" c
SET
    stage = CASE WHEN subquery.type in('PENDING_CALLCENTER', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER') THEN
        'AT_CALLCENTER'
    ELSE
        'AT_SITE'
    END
FROM (
    SELECT
        s. "type" AS "type",
        s.candidate_id AS "candidate_id",
        s. "timestamp" AS "timestamp"
    FROM
        statuses s
        INNER JOIN "comments" c ON s.candidate_id = c.candidate_id
            AND s. "timestamp" <= c.created_at
        GROUP BY
            "type",
            s. "candidate_id",
            "timestamp"
        ORDER BY
            s.timestamp DESC) AS subquery
WHERE
    subquery.candidate_id = c.candidate_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a query that worked fine for me and sharing it in case someone would have a similar issue

```sql
UPDATE comments com
SET stage = CASE 
        WHEN sub.type IN (
                'PENDING_CALLCENTER',
                'REJECTED_CALLCENTER'
                )
            THEN 'AT_CALLCENTER'
        ELSE 'AT_SITE'
        END
FROM (
    SELECT c.id,
        c.candidate_id,
        c.created_at,
        s.type,
        s.TIMESTAMP,
        row_number() over (partition by c.id order by s.timestamp desc) as rn
    FROM comments c
    JOIN statuses s ON c.candidate_id = s.candidate_id
    WHERE c.created_at >= s.TIMESTAMP
    ) sub
WHERE sub.id = com.id
and sub.rn = 1;
```